# remove derived data with shell script

Tags: macos, shell, rm, removeall

I'm trying to create a sh to remove the contents of Xcode's deriveddate folder. I wrote this, it goes to the desired folder, and list the content, but when I remove the # and try to delete it, than it says

```
"**line 1: =~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/: No such file or directory
Desktop     Downloads   Movies      Pictures    clitools.dmg
Documents   Library     Music       Public
override r--r--r--  dajkaferenc/staff for Desktop/Christmas Game update/.git/objects/00/8b8026f772525ccff6c3361ecc6f3eb43d0d82?** "



$DIR="~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/"
cd $DIR
ls
#rm -r -- "$DIR"*
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You cannot place `~` inside the quotes. Shell doesn't expand that.
- Variable assignment doesn't have `$` before the variable name.

Try this:

```
DIR=~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
cd $DIR
ls
rm -r -- "$DIR"*
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DIR=~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
cd "$DIR"
ls
rm -r ./*
```

No `$` when you assign a value, only when you read it.
Variables which could contain spaces or other symbols with a special meaning should be quoted.
You are already in the right folder, so you don't need the variable.